# Adding only 1 product from a <foreach tag>

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

with the gallery below everytime i click add to cart,I want it to pass the id for the particular selected item

problem:
1-the servlet adds 1 product to the cart(first one) and the url looks like this:
local.../DisplayCart?productId=01&productId=02&action=addtocart

```
  <form action="/DisplayCart">
 <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${product.name}</td>
                        <td>${product.description}</td>
                        <td>${product.price}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="${product.id}">
                            <input type="submit" name="action" value="addtocart"></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

         <form action="<c:url value='/DisplayCart'/>">
        <table>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${cart.items}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="${item.product.id}">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="quantity" value="${item.quantity}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update">
                        </td>
                        <td>${item.product.name}</td>
                        <td>${item.product.description}</td>
                        <td>${item.product.price}</td>
               <td><input type="submit" name="removeButton" value="Remove">       </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
                </form>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: no i actually want the user to be able to choose any of the items that this loop basically lists from the database.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good part of it.

replace this

```
       <td><input type="submit" name="removeButton" value="Remove">       </td>
```

with this

```
       <td><a href="<c:url value='/DisplayCart?productId=${product.id}'/>">add</a></td>
```

and the url always appears as /DisplayCart?productId=xx

happyyy

Comment: at the same time, i'll appreciate someone explaining why is it not working the previous way around ? even the removeButton is removing the first only.